# Multithreading xargs with input from cat

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a text file `files.txt` on my server, on each line is a file with the full path, e.g. `/home/lelouch/dir/randomfile.txt`.

I want to loop through files.txt, and pass each filename to another script.

I have gotten this to work like this:

```
cat /home/lelouch/dir/files.txt | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 30 /home/lelouch/bin/script.
```

The problem is, although I want to process it 30 files at a time, it's only happening 1 at a time. I've tried a few other ways, but I haven't gotten it to work like I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Good question, but no idea why -regex is so much slower. Interesting. Did you try `find /dir | xargs grep ...` OR if your system has multiple CPUs and you xargs supports the `-P` option `find /dir | xargs -P${numOfCPUS} grep ...`. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

You say that each *line* is a filepath, but you use the `-0` option of `xargs`, which switches the separator from a newline to a null character. From the `man` page:

> Input  items  are terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are not special (every character is taken literally)....

Don't use the `-0` option:

```
cat /home/lelouch/dir/files.txt | xargs -P 30 -n 1 /home/lelouch/bin/script
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: cat /home/lelouch/dir/files.txt |  parallel -P 30 /home/lelouch/bin/script

Answer (score 0):

`--max-args` is the right option you need

```
cat /home/lelouch/dir/files.txt | xargs --max-args=30 /home/lelouch/bin/script
```

Comment: Unless the script is multithreaded, which is extremely unlikely, that will only process one file at a time. To process 30 files at a time, the proper way is `xargs -P 30 -n 1 /home/lelouch/bin/script`.